# Why utf-8 character in subtitle are in different from ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to burn a subtitle file(.srt) for a .mp4 video,and this is my command:

```
ffmpeg -i my.mp4 -c:v mpeg4 -q:v 1 -vf subtitles=my.srt new.mp4
```

It is not very clear in this picture,but when I play it I am sure the are in different size.

[image]

Comment: Can you explain in detail please? I couldn't understand.

Comment: @Saibot Yeah,I want to burn a srt subtitle file to a mp4 file,but when it is done,I found the srt text is not in same size,some look small but others look bigger obviously.How can I make them in same size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to specify character encoding.

```
 -sub_charenc [character encoding]
```

So below command probably would work:

```
ffmpeg -i my.mp4 -c:v mpeg4 -q:v 1 -vf -sub_charenc [$APPROPRIATE_ENCODING_CODE] subtitles=my.srt new.mp4
```

Check language codes and other examples from [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/FFMPEG_An_Intermediate_Guide/subtitle_options).

Comment: my command:ffmpeg -i Heaps.mp4 -c:v mpeg4 -q:v 1 -vf -sub_charenc UTF-8
 "ass=Heaps.ass" new.mp4 it told me [NULL @ 00000000007892e0] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'UTF-8'
UTF-8: Invalid argument

Comment: Yeah,but if i use GBK,it wil  show the same message:[NULL @ 00000000007e92e0] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'GBK'
GBK: Invalid argument

Comment: It seems this problem only appears in Windows according to wiki,I will try out a Linux several days later.Could I have another question?the my.mp4 is about 200MB,but the output file new.mp4 is more than 1GB,how to deal with it?I want make the output file less than 250MB.

Comment: ffmpeg -i my.mp4 [$APPROPRIATE_ENCODING_CODE] subtitles=my.srt -c:v mpeg4 -q:v 1 -vf -sub_charenc  new.mp4 --- Can you please try this? I think the order is wrong.

Comment: I am do a test based on [this one](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=2554),wait a minute xD

Comment: And whats -"vf"? Isn't it missing arguments? I think -vf should be like "-vf [args]'

Comment: From ffmpeg help menu, -vf filter_graph set video filters. It's not relevant to subtitles.

Comment: Your command is wrong I think, the problem isn't about encoding.

Comment: Now my code is :ffmpeg -i my.mp4 -c:v mpeg4 -q:v 1 subtitles=my.srt ne
w.mp4      it gives a error:Output file #0 does not contain any stream

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99034/discussion-between-david-page-and-saibot).

Comment: Maybe I need to install a ffmpeg for Linux.but now i need to know how to get the output file size smaller,I need it 2 hours latter,Please help.I think the file size matters more than the subtitle xD

Comment: Maybe you should ask your questions more properly? :) The problem isn't about subtitles :)